# Best Approach for I/O Bound Problems?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, subprocess, joblib

I am currently running a code on a HPC cluster that writes several 16 MB files on disk (same directory) for a short period of time and then deletes it. They are written to disks and then deleted sequentially. However, the total number of I/O operations exceeds 20,000 * 12,000 times.

I am using the joblib module in python2.7 to take advantage of running my code on several cores. Its basically a nested loop problem with the outer loop being parallelised by joblib and the inner loop is run sequentially in the function. In total its a (20,000 * 12,000 loop.)

The basic skeleton of my code is the following.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import subprocess

def f(a,b,c,d):
    cmds = 'path/to/a/bash_script_on_disk with arguments from a,b > \
    save_file_to_disk'
    subprocess.check_output(cmds,shell=True)

    cmds1 = 'path/to/a/second_bash_script_on_disk  > \
    save_file_to_disk'
    subprocess.check_output(cmds1,shell=True)

    #The structure above is repeated several times. 
    #However I do delete the files as soon as I can using:

    cmds2 = 'rm -rf files'
    subprocess.check_output(cmds2,shell=True)

    #This is followed by the second/inner loop.

    for i in range(12000):
        #Do some computation, create and delete files in each 
        #iteration.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_cores = 48
    Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(f)(a,b,c,d) for i in range(20,000)) 

    #range(20,000) is batched by a wrapper script that sends no more \
    #than 48 jobs per node.(Max.cores available)
```

This code is extremely slow and the bottleneck is the I/O time. Is this a good use case to temporarily write files to /dev/shm/? I have 34GB of space available as tmpfs on /dev/shm/.

Things I already tested:

I tried to set up the same code on a smaller scale on my laptop which has 8 cores. However, writing to /dev/shm/ ran slower than writing to disk.

Side Note: (The inner loop can be parallelised too, however, the number of cores I have available is far lesser than 20,000 which is why I am sticking to this configuration. Please let me know if there are better ways to do this.)

Comment: Multiple cores shouldn't improve I/O bound tasks, and you may want to potentially (**highly-dependent on your workload**) compress your data before I/O using a fast compression algorithm like C-blosc before writing to disk. Benchmark it though, it might very well not work for your use-case.

Comment: Another trick may be to preallocate storage for the file and ensure it's using sequential file storage, but this will likely only help on some POSIX OSes and not on Windows and also not on some POSIX OSes (posix_fallocate is allowed to write 0s to guarantee storage, which can effectively double the time it takes to write a file in some cases).

Comment: Could you expand on the data flow surrounding the files?  For example, does anything *read* them?

Answer (score 3):

First, do not talk about **total I/O operations**, that is meaningless. Instead, talk about IOPS and throughout.

Second, that is almost impossible that writing to /dev/shm/ will be slower than writing to disk. Please provide more information. You can test write performance using `fio`, example command: `sudo fio --name fio_test_file --rw=read --direct=1 --bs=4k --size=50M --numjobs=16 --group_reporting`, and my test result is: `bw=428901KB/s, iops=107225`.

Third, you are really writing too many files, you should think about your structure.

Comment: Note that the fio line given in this answer doesn't have direct=1 thus there is a chance all the I/O could be satisfied by the kernel's buffer cache which may not be desired and could distort the results...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your temporary data size.

If you have much more memory than you're using for the data, then yes - shm will be a good place for it. If you're going to write almost as much as you've got available, then you're likely going to start swapping - which would kill the performance of everything.

If you can fit your data in memory, then tmpfs by definition will always be faster than writing to a physical disk. If it isn't, then there are more factors impacting your environment. Running your code under a profiler would be a good idea in this case.